# Socket.io + REST API + REACT - is it better to separate socket.io from REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My question could be flagged as "opinion based" but I am wondering which approach is the best for my application as I am able to do it in both ways.

I am building chat application in which users and conversations are saved in MongoDB. I will have my react application consuming API/APIs. The question is - is it better to have REST API and Socket.io applications running separate? For example:

1. Have REST API running on port 3005
2. Have Socket.io running on port 3006

React Application consuming these 2 separately and basically they will not know about each other. My endpoints in REST API endpoints and socket.io will be invoked only in front-end.

**On the other hand**, I can have my socket.io application and REST API working together in 1 big application. I think it is possible to make it working without problems.

To sum up, at first glance I would take the first approach - more cleaner and easy to maintain. But I would like to hear other opinions or if somebody had a similar project. Usually how the things are made in this kind of projects when you have socket.io and REST API?

Comment: Hi, based on your question, which scenario did you go with?

Comment: I did it both ways and I think in my case was better to separate. You can easily improve individual applications and no need to think about making error will stop both of them

Comment: I think i have that problem now, something is wrong with my socket which leads to the entire backend not being able to connect to my app. If that is the case, what are the drawbacks of having 2 separate servers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the pros and cons for both scenario. For example code and resource reusability is better if you have a single application and you don't have to care about which versions are compatible with each other. On the other hand one error can kill both applications, so from security perspective it is better to have separate applications. I think the decision depends on what pros and cons are important to you.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a separate file for `socket.io` logic like [this](https://github.com/alishefaee/modbus-tcp/blob/main/socket-server/socket.mjs):

```js
// socket.mjs file
import { Server } from "socket.io"

let io = new Server()
const socketApi = {
    io: io
}

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('client connected:', socket.id)

    socket.join('modbus-room')

    socket.on('app-server', data=>{
        console.log('**************')
        console.log(data)
        io.to('modbus-room').emit('modbus-client', data)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
        console.log(reason)
    })
})

export default socketApi
```

and add it to your project like [this](https://github.com/alishefaee/modbus-tcp/blob/main/socket-server/bin/www.mjs):

```js
// index.js or main file
//...
import socketApi from "../socket.mjs";
//...
//
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);
socketApi.io.attach(server);
//
```